# Get nearest location from JSON in localStorage and my geolocation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm stuck for 10 hours on a little Javascript. I'm a very young developer.
I stocked some locations (JSON) inside a localStorage and i would love to select all data with a certain value (for example "category = 2") then get the nearest locations of a latitude and longitude.

```js
var jsonString = "{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "places": [
        {
            "id": "564",
            "segment": "Europe (Avenue De L')",
            "adresse": "Avenue De L'Europe 58",
            "enseigne": "Eko Services",
            "responsable": "",
            "tel": "071\/30.70.02",
            "email": "charleroi@ekoservices.be",
            "site": "www.ekoservices.be",
            "categorie": "12",
            "creation": "",
            "latitude": "",
            "longitude": ""
        },
        {
            "id": "565",
            "segment": "Fort (Rue Du)",
            "adresse": "Rue Du Fort 68",
            "enseigne": "ALE Charleroi",
            "responsable": "Mme. Francia Annick (Responsable)",
            "tel": "071\/20.80.90",
            "email": "ale.charleroi@skynet.be",
            "site": "",
            "categorie": "11",
            "creation": "",
            "latitude": "",
            "longitude": ""
        },
        {
            "id": "566",
            "segment": "Beffroi (Rue Du)",
            "adresse": "Rue du Beffroi 30",
            "enseigne": "Le Chien Elegant",
            "responsable": "Mme. Cilli Christine",
            "tel": "071\/30.80.30",
            "email": "lechienelegant@skynet.be",
            "site": "www.lechienelegant.be",
            "categorie": "12",
            "creation": "",
            "latitude": "",
            "longitude": ""
        }
    ]
}  "

//var myData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("placesJSON"));

$(document).ready(function () {

    var distanceObj = [],
        i = 0;

    $.each(myData, function (a, b) {
        distanceObj[i] = { distance: hesapla(9.9608999, 49.7222842, b.places.longitude, b.places.Latitude), location: a };
        ++i;
    });

    distanceObj.sort(function(a,b) {
        return parseInt(a.distance) - parseInt(b.distance)
    });

    $.each(distanceObj, function(a, b) {
        $('#places').append('<li>' + b.location + ': ' + b.distance + 'm</li>');
    });
    
    console.log(distanceObj);

    function hesapla(meineLongitude, meineLatitude, long1, lat1) {
        erdRadius = 6371;

        meineLongitude = meineLongitude * (Math.PI / 180);
        meineLatitude = meineLatitude * (Math.PI / 180);
        long1 = long1 * (Math.PI / 180);
        lat1 = lat1 * (Math.PI / 180);

        x0 = meineLongitude * erdRadius * Math.cos(meineLatitude);
        y0 = meineLatitude * erdRadius;

        x1 = long1 * erdRadius * Math.cos(lat1);
        y1 = lat1 * erdRadius;

        dx = x0 - x1;
        dy = y0 - y1;

        d = Math.sqrt((dx * dx) + (dy * dy));


        return Math.round(d * 1000);
    };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="places"></div>
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate through the array

```js
var jsonString = {
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "places": [
        {
            "id": "564",
            "segment": "Europe (Avenue De L')",
            "adresse": "Avenue De L'Europe 58",
            "enseigne": "Eko Services",
            "responsable": "",
            "tel": "071\/30.70.02",
            "email": "charleroi@ekoservices.be",
            "site": "www.ekoservices.be",
            "categorie": "12",
            "creation": "",
            "latitude": "",
            "longitude": ""
        },
        {
            "id": "565",
            "segment": "Fort (Rue Du)",
            "adresse": "Rue Du Fort 68",
            "enseigne": "ALE Charleroi",
            "responsable": "Mme. Francia Annick (Responsable)",
            "tel": "071\/20.80.90",
            "email": "ale.charleroi@skynet.be",
            "site": "",
            "categorie": "11",
            "creation": "",
            "latitude": "",
            "longitude": ""
        },
        {
            "id": "566",
            "segment": "Beffroi (Rue Du)",
            "adresse": "Rue du Beffroi 30",
            "enseigne": "Le Chien Elegant",
            "responsable": "Mme. Cilli Christine",
            "tel": "071\/30.80.30",
            "email": "lechienelegant@skynet.be",
            "site": "www.lechienelegant.be",
            "categorie": "12",
            "creation": "",
            "latitude": "",
            "longitude": ""
        }
    ]
} 

for (place in jsonString.places) {
 if (jsonString.places[place].categorie == "12") {
     console.log(jsonString.places[place].latitude, jsonString.places[place].longitude)
 }
}
```

Comment: i have a script error when i try to run your code snippet.

Comment: If you click run code snippet it just display nothing because the fields are empty

Comment: thank you. What about sort these result by geolocation?
 i found this link but can't make it work with my value: http://jsfiddle.net/mitchmalone/Wf6qy/1/